# Best setup for ApiGateway-MicroService communication pattern in MassTransit and RabbitMQ

Tags: .net-core, masstransit

I am implementing ApiGateway-MicroService communication protocol in my app with MassTransit and RabbitMQ. That protocol is meant to replace "traditional" REST API communication between ApiGateway and Microservices (I am talking about simple request-response here and not about any kind of events, sagas, etc). So on microservice(s) side I have consumers (which respond to requests) and on ApiGateway side I have request clients. Usually microservice has let's say ~10 consumers (for example OrderingMicroservice has consumers for following requests: CreateOrder, UpdateOrder, GetOrderById, ListUserOrders etc). I am trying to figure out best topology (Masstransit + RabbitMQ) for this scenario.

Here are my goals, at least I think it should work like this:

**A.** Request messages (that are routed to consumer queue) should be durable for short time only (for example 20s) and then removed from the consumer queue (and request client should receive timeout error) and not routed to any other queue. So when microservice is temporary down or it is temporary too busy to receive next request from queue then request messages should be kept in the queue for 20s and then disappear.

**B.** Since RequestClient should timeout after ~20s, Response messages (that are routed to client "response-queue") should also be durable for short amount of time (~20s). Then they can disappear. If ApiGW is offline / too busy to receive response then response(s) should be discarded.

So basically I want to use MassTransit/RabbitMQ as a short-lived buffer between ApiGW and microservice(s).

```cs
    // ApiGw MassTransit configuration
    services.AddMassTransit(x =>
                {
                    x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
                    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
                    {
                        
                    });
                    
                    x.AddRequestClient<ICreateGroupPayload>();
                });
```

```cs
    // Service MassTransit configuration
    services.AddMassTransit(x =>
                        {
                            x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
                            var entryAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
    
                            x.AddConsumers(entryAssembly);
    
                            x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
                            {
                                cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                            });
                        });
```

```cs
// Single consumer definition in service
public class CreateGroupActionDefinition : ConsumerDefinition<CreateGroupAction>
    {
        public CreateGroupActionDefinition()
        {
            EndpointName = "group-service";
        }
    }
```

This setup creates following exchanges and queues:

```
exchange ICreateGroupPayload (fanout, durable) => bind exchange:group-service
exchange group-service (fanout, durable) => bind queue:group-service
exchange PublicGateway_bus_4wdoyyro5ycgmgbybdcx1gp3r3 (fanout, autoDelete) => bind queue:PublicGateway_bus_4wdoyyro5ycgmgbybdcx1gp3r3

queue group-service (durable)
queue PublicGateway_bus_4wdoyyro5ycgmgbybdcx1gp3r3 (x-expires: 60000)
```

When I terminate ApiGw following exchanges/queues are removed from RabbitMQ within ~1min:

```
exchange PublicGateway_bus_4wdoyyro5ycgmgbybdcx1gp3r3
queue PublicGateway_bus_4wdoyyro5ycgmgbybdcx1gp3r3
```

My questions are:

1. Should I use separate queues (endpoint names) for different consumers in a microservice? Or I can use same queue (group-service for example) for different consumers/message types?
2. How I can modify my configuration to set expiration time on my consumer queues? Right now it's durable but I want messages to be removed after ~20s. Also I think such queue should not be deleted after consumer is disconnected because it should be able to send requests even when consumer is offline (but only for 20s).
3. How I can modify my configuration to set expiration time on my request client response queue to be 20s (currently it seems it's 60s by default?).
4. Maybe someone have any other suggestions on how to adjust topology to best fit for this scenario? The aim is to have the setup as fast as possible just for simple request-response + short time buffering for edge cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the work is done by MassTransit, as you can understand from the [request](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/requests.html) documentation. You can change the default request timeout from 30 seconds to 20 seconds when adding the request client to the container. There is also an `.AddGenericRequestClient()` method to automatically add requests clients for whatever request type is needed.

You can also specify the request timeout for each request, and it will set the message TimeToLive to match that value. The responses should be sent with a TimeToLive as needed.

Comment: Thanks, it works. How about separate queue per each consumer? I guess it depends on scenario but in my case what would you suggest?

Comment: That's generally recommended, to avoid bottlenecks between different consumers/messages types.